# JBoss 7.2 - XML Error when defining jboss-all.xml

Tags: java, jboss, redhat, jboss7.x, ear

I'm trying to add an ear dependency in app X for app Y but for some reason the deployment fails to parse the xml file. I'm trying to force Y.ear to be loaded first among 5 other EAR deployments. I'm testing out `jboss-all.xml` just on app X for the time being to see if I can force Y to always be loaded before it, but there are multiple EARs deployed.

I'm following the exact RedHat guide as seen [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications)

[7.6.2. Control the Order of Deployments](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications#control_order_deployments)

Is there a bug in my version of jboss that is preventing this urn from being loaded? How would I go about loading it or what version should I be using?

System:

Product Name: JBoss EAP

Product Version: 7.2.9.GA

Release Version: 6.0.30.Final-redhat-00001

**Error**

```
"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {
        "Operation step-2" => {
            "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
                "jboss.deployment.unit.\"
                X.ear\ ".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"X.ear\"
                Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0053: Failed to parse\ "/content/X.ear/META-INF/jboss-app.xml\"
                Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at[row, col]: [2, 5]
                Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0}jboss-deployment-dependencies'
                encountered "}
            }
        }
    }
```

**jboss-all.xml**

```
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="Y.ear"/>
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid `jboss-web.xml`. If you want to add a dependency you need to use a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins [7.6.2. Control the Order of Deployments](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications#control_order_deployments)

Comment: I'm sorry, I read that completely wrong. I read jboss-web.xml not jboss-all.xml. What does this mean "Release Version: 6.0.30.Final-redhat-00001"? Is that JBoss EAP 6.0?